# Is there a way to simply use images in apps supporting iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, retina-display, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone 5 - what naming convention the new images have to follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431445/iphone-5-what-naming-convention-the-new-images-have-to-follow)

I just downloaded the new xcode and I added the new splash screen for the new screen size. So now I have 3 files :

Default.png,
Default@2x.png,
Default-568h@2x.png

Until now if I wanted to make an UIImage with it, I could just simply do that:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Default"];
```

and Default.png or Default@2x.png was automatically chosen depending on the kind of iphone the app was executed. But now with the new screen size, of course it still works for normal screen/retina screen but not with 4" screens. How can I do to detect when the app is run on an iphone 5 and then use the *-568h image ?

Comment: I guess you'd just need to do a [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]. Just like 2x images were identified and used (if present), so would the iPhone 5 images be used.

Comment: Xcode is not detecting the `-568h` or `-568h@2x` handles for any images besides the `Default.png`. Does anyone know why??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431445/iphone-5-what-naming-convention-the-new-images-have-to-follow

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `Default-568h@2x.png` image, sized `640 x 1136 px`. 
In Xcode 4.5 you can also find a new field for 4" launch image in target summary.