# Concerns about resolution size Xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store

I have two images, one image is 320 x 480 called image.png and while the other is 640 x 1096 called image@2x.png. Will my app get rejected for not being exactly twice as big as the original? I have no choice it would seem if I need to fit the image on iPhone 5. Any tips or suggestions will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming convention is incorrect.

There is a strict rule of image file naming.

For iPhone 3G/3GS with resolution 320x480, your image should be named as image.png

For iPhone 4/4S with resolution 640x960, your image should be named as image@2x.png

For iPhone 5 with resolution 640x1136, your image should be named as image-568h@2x.png

This question is a duplicate of --> [iPhone 5 - what naming convention the new images have to follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431445/iphone-5-what-naming-convention-the-new-images-have-to-follow)

Comment: what if it just a regular image, do I still use the 568h?

Comment: for regular images, you don't need to have another resolution. However, you should prepare another set of layout ( i.e. another set of XIBs, just use the @2x image set is fine, as DPI of iPhone 4 & 5 is the same  ).